# Execute queue in certain hours only

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, future, queue

How can I modify this class to execute only within office hours?

```
public with sharing class AddLeadQueue {

    public void AddLeadQueue() {
        System.debug('loaded');
    }

    @future (callout = true)
    public static void enqueue(String id) {
        Lead lead = [SELECT Id, FROM Lead WHERE Id = :id LIMIT 1];

        if (lead != null) {
            // execute
        }
    }
}
```

Not really sure even how to start. Should I add it to `Schedulable` or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if you are within `BusinessHours` as follows:

```
public static BusinessHours defaultBusinessHours
{
    get
    {
        if (defaultBusinessHours == null)
            defaultBusinessHours = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
        return defaultBusinessHours;
    }
    private set;
}
public static Boolean isWithinBusinessHours()
{
    return BusinessHours.isWithin(defaultBusinessHours.Id, Datetime.now());
}
```

From within your future method, you can avoid execution as follows:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void enqueue(String id)
{
    if (!isWithinBusinessHours())
    {
        // schedule something
        return;
    }
    // current logic
}
```

You still need to do some work to figure out *when* your `BusinessHours` restart and how to format that into a cron string, but I recommend doing some work toward that end and coming back with more specific questions.

Comment: Will that still add to the queue though? And wait for the next business hour window?

Comment: @CD-RUM Yeah, you still have to figure out when to schedule it, I think that's somewhat outside the scope of the question until you put demonstrate some attempts to solve those problems. :) Trying to give you enough information to attack them but not write all the code for you.